# Django labels for custom admin fields on inline

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm new both here and to Django, and I have a doubt about custom fields:
I'm using custom models in my admin, but I would like to change the label that shows on the tabular inline.

My model is like this:

```
ModelA(Model):
    name = Model.charField(80)
    (...)

ModelB(Model):
    modelA = ModelA
    (...)
```

then in my admin I use:

```
def name_modelA(self):
    return ("%s" % self.modelA.name)

class ModelBInlne(TabularInline):
    (...)
    fields=('field1','field2',...,name_modelA)
    (...)
```

thing is, on the admin page the label for the name comes out "name_modelA", I'd like to change it to "name". Is it possible?

Hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will get what you want with [verbose field names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names)? That controls the label for editable fields in the admin interface.

For the tabular interface, I'd say something along the following lines should do:

```
class ModelAInline(TabularInline):
    model = ModelA

class ModelAAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ ModelAInline, ]
```

This makes your `ModelA` editable inline. I'm not exactly sure how you would like to have it displayed in your `ModelB`, but perhaps you could look through [the `ModelAdmin` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) and use something from there?

Comment: I don't think I was clear enough: I have a ModelBInline in a third model (ModelC). I need the label of the name_modelA field (in the modelB inline) to display only "name". Just like verbose_name, but for a custom field

Comment: I don't really see a definition for your field anywhere, but if you've created it yourself you can set the verbose name in the constructor. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#writing-a-field-subclass), for example. In the `__init__` you could then set the name property to your liking.